# ASP.NET and Ember.js template: How to properly add components

Tags: asp.net, ember.js

I'm currently using a emberjs template for asp.net, I'm wondering how can I add components in separate files?

[Template I'm using](http://www.asp.net/single-page-application/overview/templates/emberjs-template)

The template adds files with the use of Handlebars compiler, thought I'm having problems trying to include a sub folder of compilers, given the reason that component tempaltes are named data-template-name="components/example", I can't name a file using a "/". Here's an example of how files are included:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/app").Include(
     "~/app/app.js",
     "~/app/router.js",
     "~/app/helpers.js"
     ).IncludeDirectory("~/app/routes", "*.js")
    .IncludeDirectory("~/app/models", "*.js")
    .IncludeDirectory("~/app/views", "*.js")
    .IncludeDirectory("~/app/controllers", "*.js")
);
```

At least for partials you can simply name files "_partial" and they will be added as data-template-name="_partial" and will compile. Here's how handlebars files are included:

```
 bundles.Add(new Bundle("~/bundles/templates",
     new EmberHandlebarsBundleTransform()).IncludeDirectory("~/app/templates\\", "*.hbs", true)
 );
```

Comment: Would you mind if I ask you to explain your question deeply?

Comment: I think you should be able to use build tools here to compile your handlebars templates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point is you cannot name Ember.Component like components/example. It has to be separated by '-'.

Place your components templates into ~/app/templates/components/*.hbs and then just include that directory. Compiling will be done by Ember but I suggest you to use handlebars with pre-compiling feature. Way better for performance.